# Thread 1: signal SIGABRT, black screen, and 'Could not load NIB in bundle'

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode8, swift4, simulator

When I launch the simulator, a black screen appeared! Same with an error saying "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT" in AppDelegate. Lastly, an error in the right hand corner tells me that they could not load NIB in bundle. I'm also new at coding, so I still have a lot to learn. If you like you can give me some tips. Here's my code if you need to take a look:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    public var screenWidth: CGFloat {
        return UIScreen.main.bounds.width/100
    }
    var thereIsInternet:Bool?
    var reachability:Reachability?
    var numberTowardCompletion = 0
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        barProgress.frame.size.width = 0
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
        barProgress.frame.size.width = 0
        self.reachability = Reachability.init()
        if ((self.reachability!.connection) != .none) {
            thereIsInternet = true
        } else {
            thereIsInternet = false
        }
        let when = DispatchTime.now() + 5
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: when) {

        }
    }


    @IBOutlet weak var barProgress: UIView!
    @IBOutlet var percent: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var loading: UILabel!

    func checkingInternet() {
        if thereIsInternet == true {
            loading.text = "Internet is present"
            barProgress.frame.size.width = screenWidth * CGFloat(15)
        } else {
            loading.text = "ERROR"
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Connection Problem", message: "Make sure you're connected to the internet", preferredStyle: .alert)
            let restartAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Restart", style: .default, handler: { (UIAlertAction) in
                self.startOver()
            })
            alert.addAction(restartAction)
            present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
    func startOver() {
        barProgress.frame.size.width = 0
        self.reachability = Reachability.init()
        if ((self.reachability!.connection) != .none) {
            thereIsInternet = true
        } else {
            thereIsInternet = false
        }
        let when = DispatchTime.now() + 5 // change 2 to desired number of seconds
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: when) {

        }
        checkingInternet()
    }
}
```

Comment: u use xib for the rootViewController ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in Appdelegate where ViewControllerHere is the name of the viewcontroller xib file

```
self.window.rootViewController = ViewController(nibName: "ViewControllerHere", bundle: nil)
```

[image]

Comment: where is that exactly?

Comment: in appdelegate didiFinishLaunchingWithOptions

Comment: I still get the same error

Comment: you use xib or storyboard ?? for the first vc

Comment: I used storyboard

Comment: select viewController and make initial

Comment: How do I find that option? I'm new to this